# Incorrect syntax ‘[create table statement]’ at line: 7. Table isn’t related with schema

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I'm trying this website called SQL DBM. At first, I used it for modeling a database, and then converted the diagram to SQL using the website.
[DB Modeling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykXqb.jpg)
Altough, using the same script the website gave me, when I try to import the script (either by uploading an sql file or txt, or typing) and generate the diagram, it shows the warning on the title.
I'm completely new to PL/SQL and Oracle, I'm studying it. [SQL errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyYxy.jpg)
I'm using the following script (sorry, it's not in english, I'm from Brazil):

```
-- ********************************** SqlDBM: Oracle *********************************
-- * Generated by SqlDBM: Alunos, Matérias, Provas, v3*


-- ************************************** Alunos
CREATE TABLE Alunos
(
 CodMatricula     INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Nome             VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (CodMatricula)
);
-----------------------------------------------------------
-- ********************************** SqlDBM: Oracle *********************************
-- * Generated by SqlDBM: Alunos, Matérias, Provas, v3*


-- ************************************** Materias
CREATE TABLE Materias
(
 CodMateria      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 NomeMateria     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (CodMateria)
);
------------------------------------------------------------
-- ********************************** SqlDBM: Oracle *********************************
-- * Generated by SqlDBM: Alunos, Matérias, Provas, v3*


-- ************************************** Provas
CREATE TABLE Provas
(
 CodProva         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Nota             FLOAT NOT NULL,
 CodMateria       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 CodMatricula     INTEGER NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (CodProva),
 CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (CodMateria) REFERENCES Materias (CodMateria),
 CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (CodMatricula) REFERENCES Alunos (CodMatricula)
);
```

Please help.

I expected it to generate a diagram showing the modeling of the database.

Comment: You have three primary keys all named `PK_1` you need to give them unique names. Other than that, your code is valid. As for why the website does not work; that is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: [tablename]_PK is a common convention for naming primary keys, e.g. `materias_pk`. Alternatively if the name is not important ('PK_1' suggests it is not) let the system generate a default name, e.g. by defining the column as `codmatricula integer primary key` instead of having a separate definition (it will get named something like `SYS_C009081`).

Comment: Also CamelCase may not be a good choice for naming database objects as names are not case sensitive in Oracle. Also Oracle uses varchar2 for strings - varchar is supported but the documentation advises against using it.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the same Primary Key constraint name i.e. `PK_1` for all three table Primary Key. Change the names of Primary keys such that they are different for each of the tables.

Comment: You wrote (in your answer): _Change the name to something else for the second and third tables._ In other words, the OP should change the primary key constraint name to PK_2 (for example) for both the second and third tables?

Comment: @Abra Try to change to different names like PK_2 / PK_3.

Comment: Please update your answer with the additional information, it may get lost in the comments